# Python: add ranges to a list of range while iterating over it

Tags: python, list, range, intervals, overlap

I encounter a problem and wish anyone could give me a tip to overcome it.

I have a 2D-python-list (83 rows and 3 column). The first 2 columns are the start and end positions for an interval. The 3rd column is a digit index (ex: 9.68). The list is reverse-sorted by the 3rd column.
I want to get all non-overlapping interval with the highest index.

Here is an example of the sorted list:

```
504 789 9.68
503 784 9.14
505 791 8.78
499 798 8.73
1024 1257 7.52
1027 1305 7.33
507 847 5.86
```

Here is what I tried:

```
# Define a function that test if 2 intervals overlap
def overlap(start1, end1, start2, end2):
        return not (end1 < start2 or end2 < start1)

best_list = [] # Create a list that will store the best intervals
best_list.append([sort[0][0],sort[0][1]]) # Append the first interval of the sorted list
# Loop through the sorted list
for line in sort:
    local_start, local_end = line.rsplit("\s",1)[0].split()
    for i in range(len(best_list)):
        best_start = best_list[i][0]
        best_end = best_list[i][1]
        test = overlap(int(best_start), int(best_end), int(local_start), int(local_end))
        if test is False:
            best_list.append([local_start, local_end])
```

And I get:

```
best_list = [(504, 789),(1024, 1257),(1027, 1305)]
```

But I want:

```
best_list = [(504, 789),(1024, 1257)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: how does the original list look like? Are the values strings? If yes, there are no columns just yet.

Comment: Actually, they are strings that's why I need to convert them into integer to make my test. This is a list I created with the csv.reader function in package csv.

Comment: So like this: `[['504 789 9.68'], ['503 784 9.14'], ....]`?

Comment: Yes, then I split each 'row' on whitespace to get the first and second items. These are start and end position for an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have some question about your code. Since `sort` contains strings then this line `append([sort[0][0],sort[0][1]])` does what do you expect?

Anyway, to the main part your problem is that when multiple elements exist in your list it is sufficient for just one of them to pass the overlap test to be added to the list (not what you want). E.g. when both `(504, 789),(1024, 1257)` exist then `(1027, 1305)` will be inserted to the list because it passed the test when it's compared to `(504, 789)`.

So, I made a few changes and now it seems to work as expected:

```
best_list = [] # Create a list that will store the best intervals
best_list.append(sort[0].rsplit(" ", 1)[0].split()) # Append the first interval of the sorted list
# Loop through the sorted list
for line in sort:
    local_start, local_end = line.rsplit("\s", 1)[0].split()
    flag = False # <- flag to check the overall overlapping
    for i in range(len(best_list)):
        best_start = best_list[i][0]
        best_end = best_list[i][1]
        test = overlap(int(best_start), int(best_end), int(local_start), int(local_end))
        print(test)
        if test:
            flag = False
            break
        flag = True
    if flag:
        best_list.append([local_start, local_end])
```

The main idea is to check for every element and if it passes all overlapping tests then add it (last line of my code code). Not before.

Comment: Why you use `enumerate`, there is no reference to `n` inside loop?

Comment: Yeah you are right, it's left from debugging. I will edit.

Comment: Thank you Eypros, I've spent the afternoon to test it on a boarder data set with various cases and it seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you parse your csv and already have a list with `[(start, stop, index), ....]` as `[(int, int, float), ...]` then you can sort it with the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

This means that you sort by third position and return the result in reverse order from max to min.

```
def nonoverlap(data):
    result = [data[0]]
    for cand in data[1:]:
        start, stop, _ = cand
        current_span = range(start, stop+1)
        for item in result:
            i, j, _ = item
            span = range(i, j+1)
            if (start in span) or (stop in span):
                break
            elif (i in current_span) or (j in current_span):
                break
        else:
            result.append(cand)
    return result
```

Then with the above function you will obtain the desired result. For the provided snippet you will obtain `[(504, 789, 9.68), (1024, 1257, 7.52)]`. I use here the fact that you can use `1 in range(0, 10)` which will return `True`. While this is a naive implementation, you can use it as a starting point. If you want to return only *starts* and *stops* replace the return line with `return [i[:2] for i in result]`.

**Note**: Also I want to add that your code has a logical mistake. You make a decision after each comparison, but must make a decision after you have compared to all the elements already present in yours `best_list`. That is why `(504, 789)` and `(1027, 1305)` passes your test, but should not. I wish this note will help you.

Comment: Not yet tested but could you briefly explain me how start, stop and span work? And to what correspond the underscore (ie : i, j, _ = item)?

Comment: @KMdy Since `item` is a 3 element sequence. `i,j,_ = item` means that you bind `i` ti the first element in `item`, `j` for the second and `_` for the third. `_` means a placeholder. It is a convention in Python that if you are not interested in a value, but it is needed to be syntactically correct, you assign it to `_`.